# Need to dynamically cut corners on rectangle using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. I am creating the form where the user can enter coordinates x1,x2,y1,y2 for each corner to cut it top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right. Those coordinates are in millimeters and after the user enters data He should see the following image:

[image]

The racktangle itself I presented using div

```
 <div id='detailPlot' style=' position: relative;  width:300px;height:300px;background-color:white;border:1px solid black;   ' ></div>
```

Can I cut those corners on that using Javascript and show result there?

Comment: Use canvas instead of div.

Comment: Sorry, are there any examples on how to make it using canvas?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [SVG Path](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp) instead of the `<div>` element. You can draw lines between defined coordinates using it's `d` property:

```html
<svg id="detailPlot" height="150px" width="150px">  
   <path d="M0 0 L100 0 L150 100 L150 150 L0 150 L0 0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Using *javascript* you'll be able to change it's `d` property at will:

```
var pathElement= document.querySelectorAll("path")[0];
pathElement.d = "M0 0 L300 0 L300 300 L0 300 L0 0";    // draw a rectangle
```

Comment: Thank for your response. The idea is greate but, I am also making radius for each corner. With div border radius helped me, but not with svg.